# Android emulator won't launch on Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

I just installed the Android SDK and development environment (the one provided by Google based on IntelliJ).

I installed the Android IDE using Google's instructions here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

And I'm following their Android tutorial titled ["Building Your First App"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html). Everything works fine when I run the app on my device (a Samsung Edge S7 phone). But, when I attempt to run the "Hello World" app in an emulator, based on the Pixel virtual device, a tiny window appears for a second, then disappears and the app fails to launch.

After I read this related question, I ran the following on the command line, but it still doesn't launch the emulator. Here's the output:

```
$ ./emulator -avd pixel Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 838860800
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7328
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 3200
    Label: 
    Blocks: 204800
    Block groups: 7
    Reserved block group size: 55 Created filesystem with 57/51296 inodes and 12336/204800 blocks Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7 Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks qemu-system-i386: Could not open '/home/username/.android/avd/pixel.avd/../system-images/android-24/google_apis/x86//system.img': No such file or directory
```

The path in the very last line of output looks incorrect to me. I've built apps using the iOS SDK, but being unfamiliar with the Android dev tools, I'm not sure how to fix it. Seems to me like it's a simple little bug inserting the extra "/' character.

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Is Docker running? If so, try killing Docker and restarting the emulator. Worked for me.

Comment: I presume you mean use the command `docker kill container`? Not sure I'm doing this right, but here's output from `$ sudo docker container list
[sudo] password for mellertson: 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES`

Comment: I just stopped the docker daemon using `$ sudo systemctl stop docker`. Also verified it's stopped using `ps -elf docker`. It's still doesn't launch the emulator.

Comment: Why do you start emulator from shell? Use GUI provided by android studio. It passes additional params to configurate environment

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html  maybe u need more dtl on cli syntax on osx